# Memory efficient method String suffix

Tags: java, string, memory

I have a task which is to create a **memory efficient** method that takes a `String` consisting of numbers and removes any beginning zeros.

*For instance "001112" becomes "1112".*

```
public static String hej (String v)
{
    StringBuilder    h = new StringBuilder(v);
    while(true)
    {
        if (h.charAt(0) == '0')
            h.deleteCharAt(0);
        else
            break;
    }
    return h.toString();
}
```

This is my solution. Of course it does the work, but my question is, **is it memory efficient to use the `StringBuilder` or is it more efficient to use the String itself and for instance `v.substring()`?** Cant find too much information about what is more efficient. If anyone has links to some documentation, please share them.

Cheers

Comment: You could return the rest of the string using substring when you reach a character that isn't '0', that way you won't have to create the stringbuilder object.

Comment: The StringBuilder class is the most recommended method when you're working with strings.

Comment: @user3284549 yes, I know that. Although the question remains. which one would be more efficient? The StringBuilder seems more adaptable to changes of course, but does it consume more space than doing the substring, the way you suggested?

Comment: you can always look at the implementations of both?  jvm source code is available online.

Comment: The most efficient would be to use `input.substring(<first index of nonzero char>)`, calculating the index beforehand with a simple for loop

Comment: @jtahlborn any link please?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=openjdk+source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `String.substring(int)` method will be the least memory used

```
public static String hej(String input)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        if(input.charAt(i) != '0')
            break;
    return input.substring(i);
}
```

Source code from `String`:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

This calls the `String(char[], int, int)` constructor

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count <= 0) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
        }
        if (offset <= value.length) {
            this.value = "".value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

Using a `StringBuilder` uses a bit of memory to create the `StringBuilder` for the size of the input, while using `String.substring(int)` will just use up as much memory as needed to represent the modified input

Comment: this answer was very good indeed. The last explanation was very good, because I really haden't thought about it in that context. Guess I mixed up memory and performance! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: When you say "Source code from `String`", which Java implementation are you referring to?

Comment: @PeterSW Oracle's implementation, 1.8.0_65

Answer (score 1):

If your string were to have `n`  amount of  leading zeros, then using String instead of StringBuilder would consume  `n` times more memory. You know that String creates a new space in memory everytime some `char` changes in it so `StringBuilder` is the way to go.

Keep in mind

> Every string builder has a capacity. As long as the length of the
>   character sequence contained in the string builder does not exceed the
>   capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer. If
>   the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

So

> String
>
> String is immutable  ( once created can not be changed )object  . The
>   object created as a String is stored in the  Constant String Pool  . 
>   Every immutable object in Java is thread safe ,that implies String is
>   also thread safe . String can not be used by two threads
>   simultaneously. String  once assigned can not be changed.
>
> String  demo = " hello " ; // The above object is stored in constant
>   string pool and its value can not be modified.
>
> demo="Bye" ;     //new "Bye" string is created in constant pool and
>   referenced by the demo variable              // "hello" string still
>   exists in string constant pool and its value is not overrided but we
>   lost reference to the  "hello"string
>
> StringBuffer
>
> StringBuffer is mutable means one can change the value of the object .
>   The object created through StringBuffer is stored in the heap .
>   StringBuffer  has the same methods as the StringBuilder , but each
>   method in StringBuffer is synchronized that is StringBuffer is thread
>   safe .
>
> Due to this it does not allow  two threads to simultaneously access
>   the same method . Each method can be accessed by one thread at a time
>   .
>
> But being thread safe has disadvantages too as the performance of the
>   StringBuffer hits due to thread safe property . Thus  StringBuilder is
>   faster than the StringBuffer when calling the same methods of each
>   class.
>
> StringBuffer value can be changed , it means it can be assigned to the
>   new value . Nowadays its a most common interview question ,the
>   differences between the above classes . String Buffer can be converted
>   to the string by using  toString() method.
>
> StringBuffer demo1 = new StringBuffer("Hello") ; // The above object
>   stored in heap and its value can be changed . demo1=new
>   StringBuffer("Bye"); // Above statement is right as it modifies the
>   value which is allowed in the StringBuffer

[Java Hungry](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/difference-between-string-stringbuilder.html)

Comment: To be even more space efficient, creating a `StringBuilder` from the full input will use up the full input's length of space.  If you instead just use `input.substring(<index of first nonzero char>)`, then you will use up less memory.  The values are so small that there will not be much of a difference regardless of approach

Comment: What is the source of the text you're quoting?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html and 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int) and 
http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/difference-between-string-stringbuilder.html

Comment: @PeterSW Should I place the sources in the answer ? I've been quoting not so long a go, Is this necessary ?

Comment: I would definitely always at least state where you are quoting from directly in the answer. Without atributution quoting is plagerism: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism
It also has the benefit of increasing readers confidence in the text you're quoting.